# Proving Non-metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Maybe this question seems easy, but is there a strategy or a property to look for when demostrating a space is non-metrizable? Because a part from the fact that I can't find a metric generating the space, I cannot seem to find a way to prove that such does not exist.

Comment: It depends on the space, doesn't it? That question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prove that the space fails some sort of separation axiom that metric spaces have (basically any of the $T$'s [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space), or show it is not first countable.

Comment: There is something I do not remember properly tickling my mind. Something about having a closed, uncountable discrete subspace. Unfortunately I am not sure the conclusion was "it's not metrizable" but I wonder if anyone recognizes this weird ghost memory.

Comment: Any uncountable discrete space is metrisable by the discrete metric.

Comment: @TomekKania It could be totally unrelated. I just remember something like that being used to rule out a topological property.

Comment: @rschweib, this rules out separability of metrics spaces.

Comment: @TomekKania I can see that, but I'm pretty sure it was something less trivial :) It's not important if we don't figure it out...

Comment: This also rules out the Lindelöf property. (Btw. can you drop me an email please?)

Comment: @rschwieb E.g. the square of the Sorgenfrey line has a uncountable discrete subset, so cannot be second countable, while it is separable which for metric spaces would imply second countable. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Disprove for a space $X$ a property P such that all metric spaces have property P.

Such P include $X$ is Hausdorff, $X$ is normal, $X$ is perfectly normal, $X$ is first countable.

Also for metric spaces we have that 
being ccc, separable, Lindelöf, second countable are all equivalent (if $X$ is metrisable and has one of these properties, it has all the other ones). If for some $X$ we have that e.g. $X$ is separable but not second countable (as for the Sorgenfrey line  (aka the lower limit topology)) then $X$ cannot be metrisable.

For metric spaces we also have that countably compact, pseudocompact, compact
and sequentially compact are all equivalent, so here the same strategy can be applied. e.g. $\omega_1$ is countably compact but not compact, so cannot be metrisable.

I think most proofs of non-metrisability are done along these lines. 
A totally general method is not really possible I think.